# Is there a way to print one XGBoostRegressor tree in python?

Tags: python, xgboost

I have constructed a XGBoostRegressor model where I now want to try and plot one of the trees. I know that regular xgb classifier has the function plot_tree but unfortunately XGBoostRegressor does not. Is there any other way to plot the tree? I also tried importing plot_tree from xgboost and use plot_tree(xgb) which returns

```
ValueError('Unable to parse node: 44['product_family'])
```

Any ideas if there is any other way in doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, I had some whitespace in some of my feature names. I added the following line

```
    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(" ", "_")
```

And now it worked to use the plot_tree(xgb).